# nginx differences between stream module and http module

Tags: nginx, http, stream

I'm try to understand nginx http and stream module, so far I learn that http module is for L7 operations and stream module is for L4 operations? Is that all or is much more here?

With Regards

Boris

Comment: Isn't it enough difference?

Comment: Hello Alex, Thank You for response. I'm confused because I found  in nginx documentation how to re-encrypt to upstream server in stream module, and if I'm not wrong encryption and decryption should occurred in OSI L6.

Comment: Well, OSI is an ideal abstration, but in real world one have to deal with several levels. E.g. in http module you configure how sockets will behave, and that is L5 (or L4, definetely not L7). So I would say key difference that `http` is about HTTP (L7), while `stream` could handle any connection type.